# Looking for a simple component that can draw rectangles and move the on screen using Angular(8)

Tags: angular, drawing, shapes

I am looking for an Angular Component that can do the following

1. Draw rectangles on screen
2. User would be able to move then around and resize them

Started to do it by just manipulating div elements but I think that such component probably already exists.

Below is an example from what I want to achieve

Any idea of the best why to do it?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Angular material has a good drag/drop module which could be used to handle the manipulation side, link: https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

There is also native browser drag/drop methods: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

As for drawing, there's quite a lot of tools that you can use, I would recommend searching on google or npm, trying some out, putting some code down and then coming back here if you have any specific issues (as everything else will mostly just be down to opinion)